# Combining two php codes

Tags: php

So right now I have 2 php codes that work exactly as they are supposed to

the first one pulls all info from the "src" of an "img" tag

```
<?php
$url="foo";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {

       echo $tag->getAttribute('src') . "<br>";
}
?>
```

the second one is designed to pull a string of characters from between two others strings

```
<?php
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);   
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fullstring = "this is my [tag]dog[/tag]";
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "[tag]", "[/tag]");

echo $parsed; // (result = dog)
?>
```

what I need is to figure out how to use the second code to only pull a piece of the "src" and replace it for as long as there are still "img" tags to process

so if the tag comes back "/pics/foo.jpg" i can remove the "/pics/" and the ".jpg" leaving me with just "foo"

i hope i have made some sense. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use the second code? You can do it with exploding the fullstring:

`$exploded_tag = explode($tag,'\');`

Then you need the last element of the string (foo.jpg):

`$last_part = end($exploded_tag);`

Then you have to explode it and take the first element (foo):

```
$exploded_lastpart = explode($last_part,'.');
$piece = $exploded_lastpart[0];
```

Comment: im trying to follow, some what new to PHP, can you please show me how i would implement this into the original code?

Comment: cdn-8.psndealer.c0m/e2/dealersite/images/bluffcreekmarina/vp3942837_0.jpg

thats the "src" for one of the images, i need to extract the 3942837, omitting the "_0" and the "/vp"

Comment: You said if you have "pics/foo.jpg" you just need the "foo". So you have "pics/vpfoo_0.jpg"? Or do you need the numbers from the filename?

Comment: i need the numbers from the file name

Answer (score 0):

You don't need second code. There is function in PHP called [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.pathinfo.php). So you can just do:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/pics/foo.jpg');
echo $path_parts['filename'];
```